# Using brace expansion in if statement

Tags: bash, shell

Let's say I've got a list with file names in it with date. I want to do something on files with extension *png* or *jpg* of a specific date. I've got the following code:

```
year="2015"
for f in $myFiles
do
    if [[ $f = *"$year"{".png",".jpg"} ]]
    then
        echo $f
    fi
done
```

This doesn't seem to work, no file passes the condition. I could do it by using two conditions, and using an `or` condition; but I was wondering what I am doing wrong. Brace expansion should work, otherwise how should I use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`{...}` doesn't expand for `if` condition. You can use `extglob`:

```
shopt -s extglob

[[ $f = *"$year".@(png|jpg) ]] && echo "$f"
```

You may not even need a for loop with `extglob`, you can just do:

```
printf "%s\n" *"$year".@(png|jpg)
```

Comment: I didn't know about this before, it's cool. Do you where I can get more info on the options of `shopt` I tried man, nothing came up. I can see other options by not suppling any arguments though I don't know what they mean. Also do you know of a way to turn on other options like `autocd` for all future logins, other than adding it to `.bashrc`?

Comment: You can do `help shopt` and just `shopt` to see what options are set in your shell.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Bash regex matching:

```
pat="(.*)($year)(\.png|\.jpg)"
...
if [[ $f =~ $pat ]]
```

Example:

```
year="2015"
pat="(.*)($year)(\.png|\.jpg)"
for f in $myFiles
do
    if [[ $f =~ $pat ]]
    then
        ext="${BASH_REMATCH[3]}" # This is the extension, .png or .jpg
        # Additionally ${BASH_REMATCH[1]} is the part before $year in $f.
        echo "$f" "$ext"
    fi
done
```

Comment: `(\.png|\.jpg)` could be shortened to `\.(png|jpg)`. (Or even `\.(pn|jp)g`, but that's a bit silly.)

Comment: @Biffen then `$ext` would contain `png` not `.png`. I wanted it to be `.png` for convenience, and note that `(\.png|\.jpg)` is a captured group.

Comment: Fair point. `(\.(png|jpg))` could be a compromise. Or `ext=".${BASH_REMATCH[3]}"` ☺

Comment: @Biffen yap, there are various ways to do the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

You can also make use of **parameter expansion/substring extraction** to construct a test as well:

```
year="2015"
for f in $myFiles
do
    if [ x${f##*${year}.jpg} = x -o x${f##*${year}.png} = x ]
    then
        echo $f
    fi
done
```

**Note:** `x` is simply appended to both sides of the test to avoid checking for empty string (e.g. instead of `"${f##*${year}.jpg}" = ""`)